# Прием данных через вебсокет

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Здравствуйте!
В компоненте хочу реализовать прием данных по вебсокету, соединение устанавливается, но внутри onopen не происходит отправка send https://jsfiddle.net/cergey251/tchxpbv4/.

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    socket: null,
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  },
  created() {
    this.socket = new WebSocket('wss://api2.poloniex.com/');

    this.socket.onopen = function() {
        this.send(JSON.stringify({
        command: 'subscribe',
        channel: 1002
      }));
    }
  }
})
```

Аналогичный код работает на чистом js, данные корректно приходят https://jsfiddle.net/cergey251/okxw3dtq/.

```
var socket = new WebSocket('wss://api2.poloniex.com/');

socket.onopen = function() {
    socket.send(JSON.stringify({
        command: 'subscribe', 
        channel: 1002
    }));

    socket.send(JSON.stringify({
        command: 'subscribe', 
        channel: 'USDT_XRP'
    }));
};

socket.onmessage = function(event) {
    var msg = JSON.parse(event.data);
    console.log(msg);
};
```

В чем может быть проблема? 
Буду очень признателен за помощь)

Answer (score 0):

А чего вы ждали? У вас вызывается `this.send`, но метод не определен.
Видимо надо `this.socket.send`?